undefined references building clang ast ToolTemplate.cpp
I'm trying to build my first clang AST tool on windows 10. I want develop on visual studio code in c++ - I can live with any compiler that works...
I've looked at the clang documentation , YouTube videos and stack overflow and - I'm still no there?
I finally got the "tools/extra/ToolTemplate.cpp" example to pass the compile by

Installing visual studio studio community 22022
installing mysys2 and mingw - using the cmake kit rfom mingw (g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3) 8.2.0)
building using cmake build from studio code

Now I'm failing the build with undefined references such as
    clang::tooling::AtomicChange::AtomicChange(
    clang::NamedDecl::getQualifiedNameAsString
    clang::tooling::ExecutionContext::reportResult
    clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder::MatchCallback::~MatchCallback()
    llvm::sys::PrintStackTraceOnErrorSignal
    clang::tooling::createExecutorFromCommandLineArgs
    llvm::errs
    llvm::toString[abi:cxx11]
    clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder::MatchFinder

and more....
There are so many libraries in the binary, and I see no documentation as to which API is is which library.
What am I missing (apart from the correct libraries) - cmakd ast looks like a great concept - is it really so hard to get started or did I miss the full tutorial?
The link line is

C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe
-g   CMakeFiles/canalDoc.dir/main_clang.cpp.obj -o canalDoc.exe -Wl,
--out-implib,libcanalDoc.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,
--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/install/clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib
-lclangAST  -lclangASTMatchers  -lclangBasic  -lclangFrontend
-lclangSerialization  -lclangTooling  -lkernel32
-luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32
-luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

The CMakeLists.txt file is

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
    project(canalDoc VERSION 3.5.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
      
    include_directories(C:/install/clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/include)
    link_directories(C:/install/clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib)
    add_executable(canalDoc main_clang.cpp)
    
    target_link_libraries(canalDoc
        PRIVATE
        clangAST
        clangASTMatchers
        clangBasic
        clangFrontend
        clangSerialization
        clangTooling
    )


